# vb.net syntax error in INSERT INTO statement

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I get syntax error in INSERT INTO statement when trying to insert into access db. The snippet where the error occurs is,

```
 If (checkBox.IsChecked) Then
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Participants([Full Name],[From],[Gender],[Category],[Event],[Weight],[DOB],[Age]) VALUES(" + textBox.Text + "," + textBox_Copy2.Text + "," + gender + "," + comboBox.SelectedItem.ToString + "," + "Kata" + "," + textBox_Copy.Text + "," + dp.Text + "," + textBox_Copy1.Text
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End If
    If (checkBox_Copy2.IsChecked) Then
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Participants([Full Name],[From],[Gender],[Category],[Event],[Weight],[DOB],[Age]) VALUES(" + textBox.Text + "," + textBox_Copy2.Text + "," + gender + "," + comboBox.SelectedItem.ToString + "," + "Kumite" + "," + textBox_Copy.Text + "," + dp.Text + "," + textBox_Copy1.Text
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End If
    If (checkBox_Copy1.IsChecked) Then
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Participants([Full Name],[From],[Gender],[Category],[Event],[Weight],[DOB],[Age]) VALUES(" + textBox.Text + "," + textBox_Copy2.Text + "," + gender + "," + comboBox.SelectedItem.ToString + "," + "Team Kata" + "," + textBox_Copy.Text + "," + dp.Text + "," + textBox_Copy1.Text
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End If
    If (checkBox_Copy.IsChecked) Then
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Participants([Full Name],[From],[Gender],[Category],[Event],[Weight],[DOB],[Age]) VALUES(" + textBox.Text + "," + textBox_Copy2.Text + "," + gender + "," + comboBox.SelectedItem.ToString + "," + "Team Kumite" + "," + textBox_Copy.Text + "," + dp.Text + "," + textBox_Copy1.Text
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End If
```

Comment: A part from the syntax error, are you sure that you want to insert 4 records if the user checks all the 4 checkboxes?

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: See also [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For text fields you have to enclose the value in the VALUES clause in quotes.  Note the single quotes in this example

```
"INSERT INTO Participants([Full Name]) VALUES ('" + textBox.Text + "')"
```

However you would be much better off using parameters instead of putting the values right in the SQL statement.  See this 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tyy0sz6b(v=vs.110).aspx